# Adding new methods to Cocos2d-x SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: java, android, c++, audio, cocos2d-x

In Cocos2d-x (3.6) I am trying to add increased functionality to SimpleAudioEngine.  Specifically, with regard to Android's SoundPool (which SimpleAudioEngine is based upon, at least for Android), I am trying to add some of the methods that have not yet been implemented but are documented in the Android Developer web site.

For example, SoundPool's play method includes a loop variable that is of type int, whereas in SimpleAudioEngine it is of type bool (boolean on the Java side).  If I can implement a new method with the loop variable as type int, I will be able to control the number of repetitions directly when I call the playEffect method.

I have figured out most of the changes required, including various C++ header and .cpp files (cocos/audio/include/SimpleAudioEngine.h, cocos/audio/android/cddSimpleAudioEngine.cpp, cocos/audio/android/jni/cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.h, and cocos/audio/android/jni/cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.cpp) and also the Cocos2dxSound.java file, but I am still getting error messages saying that my new method (which I am calling playEffectN) cannot be found.

The only other place I can see where something might need to be added is in the cocos/audio/openal/SimpleAudioEngineOpenAL.cpp file, but I'm not quite sure how to modify that in order to add my new method.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what else I need to do in order to add this additional functionality to SimpleAudioEngine?  If I am successful, I will gladly share the results.  (If successful, I will also be able to add some of the other unimplemented methods in SoundPool, such as setLoop, setPriority, setRate, and setVolume, for sounds that have already been assigned a soundID.)

Answer (score 0):

first, add c++ apis, in :

```
cocos/audio/include/AudioEngine.h
```

though there is no implement in cddSimpleAudioEngine.cpp, you still need to declare functions in  AudioEngine.h

then, the bridge btween c++ and java:

```
cocos/audio/android/jni/cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.h
cocos/audio/android/jni/cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.cpp
```

here, declare in cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.h and implement in cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.cpp, like

```
 void AndroidJavaEngine::playEffectN(int times) {
        cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;

        if (! getJNIStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "playEffectN", "(I)V")) {
            return ;
        }

        methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, times);
        methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
    }
```

then in java

```
cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper.java
```

add function like:

```
public static void playEffectN(int times) {

}
```

finally is your java implement, in

```
cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxMusic.java
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I don't think that cocos/audio/include/AudioEngine.h needs to be changed, because it doesn't include the original (playEffect).  Same applies to Cocos2dxMusic.java.  It turns out I had missed Cocos2dxHelper.java, but I still can't get it to compile.  The documentation says that CocosDenshion is based on openAL, and there IS a reference to playEffect in cocos/audio/openal/SimpleAudioEngineOpenAL.cpp, so I strongly suspect that I need to add playEffectN to that source file, as well.

Comment: I made some progress on this.  It appears that in order to add new methods (in Android, using existing SoundPool methods), the following files need to be edited:

    cocos/audio/include/SimpleAudioEngine.h
    cocos/audio/android/cddSimpleAudioEngine.cpp
    cocos/audio/android/jni/cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.h
    cocos/audio/android/jni/cddandroidAndroidJavaEngine.cpp
    platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper.java
    platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxSound.java

Comment: Then, if you are using the new method(s) in a project that already exists, you have to copy the new files over to the cocos and platform directories within your existing project's directory structure.

Before recompiling, to force your new methods to be included, from your proj.android directory, do "rm -r obj".  I did all of the above, recompiled, and was able to successfully compile and install my Android app, but then I got a run-time error (E/JniHelper(32099): Failed to find static method id of playEffectN), which resulted in no sound output.

Comment: I tracked that down to a typo in cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxSound.java (I mistakenly called "doPlayEffect" instead of "doPlayEffectN", which resulted in a mismatch in the JNI method signature (boolean instead of int).  However, I'm still getting the same error (Failed to find static method id of playEffectN), and no sound output.